# Sort folder contents, modify file with LastWriteTime

Tags: powershell

Have this code:

```
gci D:\Files\Folder |
    sort LastWriteTime | select -Last 1 |
    foreach-object {$line -replace "\<", ""}
```

Not working.  Tried many variations.  Need to replace the "<" character in the file last modified in Folder. Managed to have the correct file selected and written to powershell console.  Just cannot remove the "<" character from the file with LastWriteTime.

Comment: possible duplicate of [string replace file content with powershell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17144355/string-replace-file-content-with-powershell)

Comment: above referenced link as possible duplicate is for a static path to a specific file.  There will be 7 files referenced over a 30 minute period.  Need dynamic function.

Comment: The meat of your problem isn't finding the file(s), it's doing the replacement itself. The technique linked will work for you, you just have to adapt *how* you're referencing the file.

Comment: The meat of my problem is that I can do it with a static path and specific file.  Can't do it dynamically.   This works: (Get-Content D:\Files\Files_To_TIPWEB\astclasses.txt) | 
Foreach-Object {$_ -replace "\<", ""} | 
Set-Content D:\Files\Files_To_TIPWEB\astclasses.csv    But it does me no good as it is not dynamic.

Comment: Appreciate your feedback.  Also looking at a vbs alternative to powershell script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows doesn't allow the < character in file names so I guess you want to modify the file contents removing all occurrences. If so, there are many ways to do that. Example:

```
# Getting the name of the last modified file.
$file_name = Get-ChildItem D:\Files\Folder | Sort-Object LastWriteTime `
    | ? { ! $_.PSIsContainer } | Select-Object -Last 1 | % {$_.FullName }
# Reading the file into a single string.
$string = Get-Content $file_name | Out-String
# Modifying the string and writing the output back to the file.
$string -replace "<", "" | Out-File $file_name
```

The problem with your initial code is that $line is not defined anywhere. You need to read text from the file first.

Comment: trying to mod the content of a text file that is dynamically selected based on being the most recently modified file in a folder.  Want to take the "<" character and make it nothing within a text file.

Comment: Ok, awesome, that works wonderfully!   However, instead of decreasing the file size by 750KB, the file size almost doubles.  File size before your ps script = 350KB.  File size after mod = 552KB.   When I run the static path ps script it drops the file size down to 272KB.  Row count is the same. <shrugs>.  Thanks!

Comment: It's outputting in a different character set. Use `-encoding ascii` and it'll probably shrink to what you're expecting.

Comment: That may be what is creating the issue in the first place.  Using a Talend job to generate the file.  Currently generating file with vbs script.  DB2 LUW.  Attempted "<" removal with Talend, decided to just create a ps or vbs script and call via the Talend command line object.  So Thanks!  Have a great weekend!  -Edit to previous post: The file size is decreasing by 75KB not 750KB.

Comment: Note that in PSv3+, you can use **Get-ChildItem**'s **-File** switch instead of piping through `?{! $_.PSIsContainer}`. Also, although it doesn't apply in this case, you can avoid annoyances related to how .NET methods handle paths (using a different working directory than PowerShell) by using native PowerShell to read the file into a single string: `$string = gc $file_name | Out-String`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to replace the < in the filename then this should work:

```
foreach-object {$_.Name.Replace("<", "")}
```

To edit the contents of the file you could do this:

```
$file = gci D:\Files\Folder | sort LastWriteTime | select -Last 1
$temp = $file | gc | foreach-object {$_.Replace("<", "")}
$temp | Out-File $file.FullName
```

Comment: Trying to replace the < within the text file that was last modified in Folder.  Do not wish to modify the file name.  I can have the < within the text file be any other character that will not appear within the 7 data extracts.

Comment: Added another option to change the contents. It's more or less the same as what Alexander offered.

Comment: Will add to personal ps library also.  Appreciate your time.

Comment: Marking an answer as good and/or up-voting is always a nice gesture if it works for you or puts you on the right path...

Comment: Don't have enough reputation points to up vote.  Since I used Alexander's code, green check there.  Have an awesome weekend!  Thanks again.