# PowerShell Get-Content “foreach” on multiple files from multiple directories

Tags: powershell

I want to search the content of specific folder for `Web.config` files.
Here's the script I'm using but it doesn't work and don't know how to tweak it.

```
$folders=get-childitem E:\WebSystems\Configs\ | select Name
foreach($folder in $folders)
{
    get-content E:\WebSystems\Configs\$folder\Web.config
}
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try the following code ,

```
$folders=get-childitem E:\WebSystems\Configs\ | select Name
foreach($folder in $folders)
{
$folderName = $folder.Name;
get-content E:\WebSystems\Configs\$folderName\Web.config
}
```

And please ensure the Folder *E:\WebSystems\Configs* has only subfolders and no files. If you are still facing error, please post the exact error details.

Comment: You're the man!

I also just found another way:

get-childitem E:\WebSystems\Configs\ | Foreach-Object{get-content E:\WebSystems\Configs\$_\Web.config}

Comment: By the way, how to do you replace a string to those individual files?

Comment: Thanks , I just found something simliar in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17144355/string-replace-file-content-with-powershell) , see if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
get-childitem E:\WebSystems\Configs\* -include Web.Config -recurse
```

What do you want to do with the collection of Web.Config files? (Get-Content probably isn't very helpful because the output won't tell you which files is in which directory.)

Answer (score 0):

You can just do

```
get-content E:\WebSystems\Configs\*\Web.config
```

to get an array of all Web.config files.
If you want to iterate over each file you can do

```
get-childitem E:\WebSystems\Configs\*\Web.config | foreach{
  get-content $_.fullname }
```

For seaching you can then use

```
Get-Help Select-String
```