# Update globalassemblyinfo.cs with a dynamic file

Tags: powershell, versioning, assemblyinfo

I got a text file with a version number which updates on each build i.e: 1.4.10.301.

I would like to insert this number on each build to my globalassemblyinfo.cs file on this line: [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.4.10.300")] and only to the version number, meaning before the build the globalassembly.cs file would be updated with the new version number from the text file (1.4.10.301).

Tried this:

```
$a = cat "C:\pathtofile\GlobalAssemblyInfo.cs" | select-string AssemblyVersion
```

which gives me only this line:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.4.10.331")]
```

but from it I need only the number how can I pull it out? Tried using a pattern but I didn't know what to put in the pattern exactly

The code below worked like a charm and I had managed to extract the version number, now i'm trying to replace this version with the one in globalassemblyinfo.cs, so I wrote this line:

```
$a -replace $version,$Newversion | Set-Content "C:\pathtofile\GlobalAssemblyInfo.cs"
```

But it deleted the whole file content and put this string instead:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.4.10.400")]
```

How can I just update the line without deleting the whole file content?

Comment: Don't make a comment. Edit your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, apparently you have to use Get-Content command with parenthesis like this :

```
(Get-Content "C:\pathtofile\GlobalAssemblyInfo.cs") -replace $version,$Newversion | Set-Content "C:\pathtofile\GlobalAssemblyInfo.cs"
```

This link helped: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17145810/4333722

Answer (score 1):

Once you've got the line containing the `AssemblyVersion` attribute, you can grab the version field with a [named capture group](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#named_matched_subexpression), like this:

```
if($a -match '(?<version>(\d+\.?){4})'){
    $version = $Matches["version"]
}
```

The actual pattern: `(\d+\.?){4}` matches four consecutive occurrences of one or more digits and an optional dot - the `(?<version>)` part makes sure it gets captured into `$Matches["version"]`