# Simplest way of removing all instances of a word from a text file

Tags: text, command-line

I have a large text file which contains numerous instances of the word 'Ref' (from where the text was copied from a website which contained a reference). I only want to keep the original website text without these instances of 'Ref'. I was wondering what is the simplest way of removing all instances from the text file? Is is possible via command line using windows cmd or cygwin?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String replace file content with PowerShell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17144355/string-replace-file-content-with-powershell)

Comment: In cygwin: `sed -i.old 's/Ref//g' yourfile.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you necessarily need the command line to do such a task. I would recommend that you do a Ctrl+F (PC) Command+F (Mac) find all "Ref" and replace with empty string (in other words leave the replace box empty). Hit enter and all done!

Hope this helps!