# Delete specific content from a text file using windows batch script

Tags: batch-file

A very simple one, see if you can give me a hand...

I have multiple files, extension .tfm (which is actually a simple text file).
The format inside each of them is always like this:

```
-2.90913045e-003   -6.36480816e-001   -7.71287046e-001    2.09995523e+001
-7.30901280e-004    7.71291457e-001   -6.36481700e-001    5.08653785e+002
 9.99995501e-001   -1.28787360e-003   -2.70899210e-003    1.04250041e+003
 0.00000000e+000    0.00000000e+000    0.00000000e+000    1.00000000e+000
Units: mm
# rotation x: 9.02438607e+001
# rotation y: -5.04696056e+001
# rotation z: 9.02618771e+001
# translation x: 2.09995523e+001
# translation y: 5.08653785e+002
# translation z: 1.04250041e+003
```

All I want to do is to remove the rotation, translate writing and stuff and leave it like this:

```
-2.90913045e-003   -6.36480816e-001   -7.71287046e-001    2.09995523e+001
-7.30901280e-004    7.71291457e-001   -6.36481700e-001    5.08653785e+002
 9.99995501e-001   -1.28787360e-003   -2.70899210e-003    1.04250041e+003
 0.00000000e+000    0.00000000e+000    0.00000000e+000    1.00000000e+000
Units: mm
9.02438607e+001
-5.04696056e+001
9.02618771e+001
2.09995523e+001
5.08653785e+002
1.04250041e+003
```

At the end, change the format to ".trm" and I don`t have to keep the original file.

Help?

THank you very much in advance.

Comment: Do you have to keep any blank lines that are in the original file?

Comment: the format of the matrix has to stay the same.
but there is no blank lines.

Comment: Have you tried anything on your own? please post your code...

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
FOR /f "delims=" %%r IN (
'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.tfm"'
) DO (
 (
 FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%s IN ("%sourcedir%\%%r") DO (
  FOR /f "tokens=1-3*delims=: " %%a IN ("%%s") DO (
   IF "%%a"=="#" (
    IF "%%b"=="rotation" ECHO(%%d
    IF "%%b"=="translation" ECHO(%%d
   ) ELSE ECHO(%%s
  )
 )
 )>"%destdir%\%%~nr.trm"
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

Read the directory for filenames matching `*.tfm` into `%%r`

Read each of those files line-by-line to `%%s`

Examine `%%s` for tokens using <kbd>space</kbd> and <kbd>:</kbd> as delimiters. Assign the tokens to %%a..%%d

If `%%a` is not `#`, simply reproduce the line, otherwise reproduce `%%d` (the part following the first 3 tokens) if the second token is one of the keywords.

Destination Filename is constructed from the destination directoryname plus the name-part of the original file + `.trm`

Answer (score 0):

I have used this in the past:
http://fart-it.sourceforge.net/

FART, Find And Replace Text, works well.

Might be your best bet if you're happy to use 3rd party software.

Comment: Just tried using fart with your file example using this code `c:\scripts\fart\fart.exe test.txt -aC "# rotation x: " " "` And the problem is, it does change the file but leaves a space.

Answer (score 0):

Other than FART that I suggested I would recommend a PowerShell Script.

found this page [Replace File contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17144355/string-replace-file-content-with-powershell) on this site.

So I played around with this:

```
$content = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText("test.txt").Replace("# rotation x: ","")
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllText("test.txt", $content)
$content = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText("test.txt").Replace("# rotation y: ","")
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllText("test.txt", $content)
$content = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText("test.txt").Replace("# rotation z: ","")
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllText("test.txt", $content)
$content = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText("test.txt").Replace("# translation x: ","")
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllText("test.txt", $content)
$content = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText("test.txt").Replace("# translation y: ","")
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllText("test.txt", $content)
$content = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText("test.txt").Replace("# translation z: ","")
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllText("test.txt", $content)
```

That is giving the desired result, now all you need to do is add a rename command into the script.

```
Rename-Item c:\scripts\test.txt new_name.txt
```

So the full script would look like this: (Cleaned up so you can just change the filepath variable)

```
$filepath = "c:\test\test.txt"
$rename = $filepath.Substring(0,$filepath.Length-4) +".trm"
$content = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText("$filepath").Replace("# rotation x: ","")
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllText("$filepath", $content)
$content = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText("$filepath").Replace("# rotation y: ","")
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllText("$filepath", $content)
$content = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText("$filepath").Replace("# rotation z: ","")
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllText("$filepath", $content)
$content = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText("$filepath").Replace("# translation x: ","")
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllText("$filepath", $content)
$content = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText("$filepath").Replace("# translation y: ","")
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllText("$filepath", $content)
$content = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText("$filepath").Replace("# translation z: ","")
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllText("$filepath", $content)
Rename-Item $filepath $rename
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for everyone`s help.
At the end I did use something similar to FART but it was called TextCrawler. Worked very well...

THanks once again.
Cheers