# How to replace newline in csv with fart.exe at Windows command-line?

Tags: windows, replace, cmd

In [FART.exe find/replace tool](https://sourceforge.net/projects/fart-it/), i’m having some trouble with newline char:

```
> set lf=^& echo.
> fart myfile.csv lf "],["
Replaced 0 occurence(s) in 0 file(s).
```

Nothing gets replaced. What's the correct (and simplest) way to do this?
The line-terminators in the file might be **CarriageReturn + LineFeed**, not sure. How to check for both?

(PS, fart is the fastest replace tool i've tested on Windows. Tested much faster than [repl.bat](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qidqwztmetbvklt/Repl.bat), [jrepl.bat](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=49151#p49151), [findrepl.bat](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=48121#p48121), [sfk.ext](https://sourceforge.net/projects/swissfileknife/), and [powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17144445/209942).)

Comment: gsar seems even faster than fart http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gsar.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*edited* to adapt to comments

`fart` includes a switch (`-C` or `--c-style`) to indicate that input/output strings contain C-style extended characters. In this case quotes are not needed around the search or replacement strings as there are no special characters in the command line:

```
fart -C myfile.csv \r\n ],[
```

Comment: this might be the answer! I'm getting proper `"Replaced x occurrences in file"` But, on opening the file in text editor, i'm getting `"Lines ending in solitary carriage returns detected. Possibly a Macintosh text file (it's not). Converting to UNIX format."` How to fix? I suspect the line-terminators are CarriageReturn + LineFeed, and my fart command is only replacing the LF's.

Comment: @johnywhy, then you don't want to replace new line characters (`\n`), but carriage return characters (`\r`)

Comment: it needs both \n\r

Comment: @johnywhy, sorry, I didn't see the changes in the question.

Comment: just curious, is CR+LF as line-terminator a Windows thing?

Comment: @johnywhy, anyway, maybe they are just needed to make data coherent, but the quotes are not needed by `fart` around the square brackets.

Comment: @johnywhy, *`Windows thing`*? [not exactly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)

Comment: you're correct, double-quotes are not needed. Thx for the link, very useful! It says LF-only is standard line-terminator on Linux, and CR-only on Mac (up to v9). Those are the platforms of interest to me. thx!

Comment: Yes, "\r\n" is the standard line ending for DOS/Windows plain text files.