# Use PowerShell to replace values in INI file

Tags: powershell, replace, automation, config, ini

Using PowerShell I need to change multiple values within the following INI file.

**From This:**

**File Name:**  C:\RDX\config.ini

```
key=AppLog value=C:\Software Config\AppLog.txt
key=ErrorLog value=C:\Software Config\ErrorLog.txt
```

**To This:**

**File Name Path:**  C:\RDX\config.ini

```
key=AppLog value=D:\RDM\Controls\AppLog.txt
key=ErrorLog value=D:\RDM\Controls\ErrorLog.txt
```

Comment: It's not a standard INI file so you can simply replace the path in the entire file: [How can I replace every occurence of a String in a file with PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17144355)

Comment: Thank you - that helped.