# Replacing words in powershell using a variable

Tags: windows, shell, powershell, replace

i want to write a script that takes inputfrom the user and changes a word in a file to what the user entered.
saw some people doing it like this:

```
(Get-Content c:\temp\test.txt).replace('word1', 'word2') | Set-Content c:\temp\test.txt
```

the problem is that i want to replace a word with a **variable**, so when i put it between the commas it wont work.

i want it to be something like that:

```
$word = read-host " please enter a word"
(Get-Content c:\temp\test.txt).replace('oldtext', '$word') | Set-Content c:\temp\test.txt
```

is there any way to do that?

UPDATE:
tried it like this:

```
$path = "C:\Users\tc98868\Desktop\dsp.json"
$word = read-host "please enter a word"
(Get-Content $path).replace('dsp.tar.gz', $word) | Set-Content $path
```

and it still doesnt work.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17144355/how-can-i-replace-every-occurence-of-a-string-in-a-file-with-powershell

Comment: What version of powershell are you using?

Comment: im using powershell 2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the single quote from the `$word`

PowerShell not expanding variables inside a single quote, it threat is as a string

```
$word = read-host " please enter a word"
(Get-Content c:\temp\test.txt).replace('oldtext', $word) | Set-Content c:\temp\test.txt
```

For PS Version 2:

```
(Get-Content c:\temp\test.txt) -replace 'oldtext', $word | Set-Content c:\temp\test.txt
```

Comment: tried it this way:
    
    $path = "C:\Users\tc98868\Desktop\dsp.json"
    $word = read-host "please enter a word"
    (Get-Content $path).replace('dsp.tar.gz', $word) | Set-Content $path 
         and it still doesnt work.. have any idea why?