# How can I replace every occurrence of a String in a file with PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

This question is similar to earlier question [How can I replace every occurence of a String in a file with PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17144355/how-can-i-replace-every-occurence-of-a-string-in-a-file-with-powershell)"  except my challenge is to replace the text is multiple files.   I tried using the solution in earlier question and used a command similar like below.

```
(Get-Content .\*.txt).replace("old text", "new text") | Set-Content .\*.txt
```

It seem to work but the each file size has increased drastically to the total of files in the directory.   Although when I open any file it seems to look normal.

Anyone has ideas how to fix it.   My litmus test would be I should revert my text changes and file sizes shouldn't change at all.

Answer (score 4):

You must process the files *one at a time*:

```
Get-Item *.txt | 
  ForEach-Object { 
     $f = $_.FullName; (Get-Content $f).replace("old text", "new text") | Set-Content $f 
  }
```

Note that this will fail with completely empty (zero-byte) files.

Also, irrespective of what the encoding of the input files was, the output files will have `Default` encoding, according to the system's legacy code page (typically, a single-byte, extended-ASCII encoding).

---

As for what you tried:

- `(Get-Content .*.txt)` sends the lines from *all* `*.txt` files as a *single* array of lines through the pipeline.
- `Set-Content *.txt` then sends that one array (with replacements made) *as a whole* to *every* `*.txt` file in the current directory.