# Windows - find/replace content in a XML tag in a bunch of files with script: sed of bash or cmd batch?

Tags: xml, windows, batch-file, sed, git-bash

In my Windows 10, I have 100+ XML files under the same directory, which contain the same tag, let's say `<Number>`, with different content, such as `<Number>4564564</Number>`, or `<Number>7777</Number>`.

Now, I want to substitute all the different values with `123456`.

I installed Git bash and find `sed` may be useful. But, AFAIK, `for` in `bash` cannot iterate files under a directory, and I know no other way of iterating files in bash, instead, `FOR` in Windows batch can(correct me if I am wrong). So,

- can I iterate with batch `FOR` and in the loop, use `sed` of bash, i.e., mixing GNU bash commands and cmd commands? As I tested it seems impossible.
- if the previous is impossible, can I do it or in pure bash script, or in pure batch?

What I have is a batch like this:

```
@echo on
setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS
set here=%cd%
for /R %here% %%G in (*.xml) do (
    echo %%G
    for /F "skip=2 tokens=* " %%H in (%%G) do (
        echo %%H | sed -r 's:<Number>([0-9]+)</Number>:<Number>123456</Number>:'
    )
)
endlocal
```

Running this batch in `cmd` and Git bash gives me the same error:

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

I have Git bash installed and apparently, `sed.exe` can be found both in Git bash and `cmd`. In `cmd`, `sed --version` gives me:

```
sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a pure `sed` solution:

```
sed -r 's:<Number>([0-9]+)</Number>:<Number>123456</Number>:' -i *.xml
```

(Note, `sed` can operate on multiple files, in sequence. The `-i` flag is instructing it to do in-place edits.)

If you need to do something else alongside, you can loop over files with this pure `bash`+`sed` script:

```
for file in *.xml; do
    echo "Processing file: $file"
    sed -r 's:<Number>([0-9]+)</Number>:<Number>123456</Number>:' -i "$file"
    # ...
done
```

Comment: Great solution, working here! Now I wonder what batch lovers would say...

Comment: I'm not sure for batch lovers, but PowerShell lovers would say to use [`Get-Content .. -replace`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17144355/how-can-i-replace-every-occurrence-of-a-string-in-a-file-with-powershell). Unix lovers would say: come over, we have (more) cookies. :)