# Replace IPTC keywords in picture files

Tags: powershell, iptc

I need to change the IPTC keywords in .tif picture files.
As we exported these .tif files out of a system, the keywords all got into one string and now you can't filter on those anymore.

I want to read the keywords of every file in a folder, split them and write them back in to the file.

I searched for a solution, but I can't find anything how to read and edit the IPTC keywords with PowerShell.

I hope you can help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I replace every occurrence of a String in a file with PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17144355/how-can-i-replace-every-occurrence-of-a-string-in-a-file-with-powershell)

Comment: I don't have experience with IPTC and metadata but I would like to share you these links: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/02/06/use-powershell-to-find-metadata-from-photograph-files/ and https://herringsfishbait.com/2016/04/08/powershell-querying-formatting-and-exporting-tags-on-picture-files/