# Need to remove specific portion from rows in a csv using powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a csv file with two columns and multiple rows, which has the information of files with folder location and its corresponding size, like below

```
"Folder_Path","Size"
"C:\MSSQL\DATA\UsersData\FTP.txt","21345"
"C:\MSSQL\DATA\UsersData\Norman\abc.csv","78956"
"C:\MSSQL\DATA\UsersData\Market_Database\123.bak","1234456"
```

What i want do is remove the "C:\MSSQL\DATA\" part from every row in the csv and keep the rest of the folder path after starting from UsersData and all other data intact as this info is repetitive. So my csv should like this below.

```
"Folder_Path","Size"
"UsersData\FTP.txt","21345"
"UsersData\Norman\abc.csv","78956"
"UsersData\Market_Database\123.bak","1234456"
```

What i am running is as below

```
Import-Csv ".\abc.csv" |
    Select-Object -Property @{n='Folder_Path';e={$_.'Folder_Path'.Split('C:\MSSQL\DATA\*')[0]}}, * |
    Export-Csv '.\output.csv' -NTI
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: SO isn't a code writing service.  You're more likely to get help if you post your own attempt(s) first.

Comment: @boxdog Sure, Edited and added my script.

Comment: why do you have a **2-hours-younger repeat** of this @ Need to remove one constant portion from rows in a csv using powershell - Stack Overflow — https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54403415/need-to-remove-one-constant-portion-from-rows-in-a-csv-using-powershell

Comment: Not getting a proper solution to my query

Comment: Why not a simple text replace in the file? Could do that even in any text editor.

Comment: @marsze I need to generate such huge reports using powershell, cant do it manually.

Comment: Powershell can do that just as well as any editor. But CSV parsing is probably, especially **because** the reports are huge.

Comment: Pretty new to PS, could you please guide me to it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a job for a simple [string replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17144355/how-can-i-replace-every-occurrence-of-a-string-in-a-file-with-powershell):

```
Get-Content "abc.csv" | foreach { $_.replace("C:\MSSQL\DATA\", "") | Set-Content "output.csv"
```

or:

```
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllText("output.csv", [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText("abc.csv" ).Replace("C:\MSSQL\DATA\", ""))
```

Comment: Thank you so much Sir.
This is exactly what i needed. Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Import-Csv ".\abc.csv" |
    Select-Object -Property @{n='Folder_Path';e={$_.'Folder_Path' -replace '^.*\\(.*\\.*)$', '$1'}}, Size |
        Export-Csv '.\output.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: This one is working, but what this is doing is keeping one folder name just before the file name, but this is not giving me the output that i need, cuz there are a lot of subfolders too in this folder whose info i want to retain. Can there a way in which i can just remove the "C:\MSSQL\DATA\" portion only?

Comment: _"this is not giving me the output that i need"_  Possibly not, but it is giving the output you asked for.  Your question/example wasn't clear that part to be left was variable.