# How to replace N number of characters in a file after a specific keyword in Powershell script?

Tags: powershell

I have a file prototype as follows:

```
// <some stuff>
#define KEYWORD release01-11
// <more stuff>
```

How can I delete the last two characters in the same line as KEYWORD and replace them with two different characters (12 in this case), in order to end up with:

```
// <some stuff>
#define KEYWORD release01-12
// <more stuff>
```

I'm trying to use Clear-Content and Add-Content but I cannot get it to do what I need. The rest of the file needs to remain unchanged after these symbols have been replaced. Is there a better alternative?

Comment: What searches have you tried? For example I just searched this site using the terms "powershell replace" and this one was right at the top: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17144355/how-can-i-replace-every-occurrence-of-a-string-in-a-file-with-powershell

Comment: @Bill_Stewart I also found that one, but that one changes *every* occurrence of the string, which also messes with the rest of my file. I need to limit it to only do so after the keyword.

Comment: Do you always want to replace the trailing number with `12` or do you need to inspect and increment the current value every time?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Inspect and increment to increase the version as it develops.

Comment: If existing searches are lacking in some way, it is good practice to _note this in your question_ and explain _why_ the results don't get you where you need to go. It is also a good idea to give a code sample of what specifically you have tried and _how_, specifically, what you tried didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `-replace` regex operator to identify the relevant statements and replace/remove the trailing numbers:

```
# read file into a variable
$code = Get-Content myfile.c

# replace the trailing -XX with 12 in all lines starting with `#define KEYWORD`, with 
$code = $code -replace '(?<=#define KEYWORD .+-)\d{2}\s*$','12'

# write the contents back to the file
$code |Set-Content myfile.c
```

The regex construct `(?<=...)` is a positive lookbehind - it ensures that the following expression will only match at a position where text right behind it is `#define KEYWORD` followed by some characters and a `-`.

---

If you want to always *increment* the current value (as opposed to just replacing it with `12`), we'll need some way to inspect and evaluate the current value before doing the substitution.

The `[Regex]::Replace()` method allows for just that:

```
# read file into a variable
$code = Get-Content myfile.c

$code = $code |ForEach-Object {
  # Same as before, but now we can hook into the regex engine's substitution routine
  [regex]::Replace($_, '(?<=#define KEYWORD .+-)\d{2}\s*$',{
    param($m)

    # extract the trailing numbers, convert to a numerical type
    $value = $m.Value -as [int]
    # increment the value
    $value++
    # return the new value
    return $value
  })
}

# write the contents back to the file
$code |Set-Content myfile.c
```

In PowerShell 6.1 and up, the `-replace` operator natively supports scriptblock substitutions:

```
$code = $code |ForEach-Object {
  # Same as before, but now we can hook into the regex engine's substitution routine
  $_ -replace '(?<=#define KEYWORD .+-)\d{2}\s*$',{
    # extract the trailing numbers, convert to a numerical type
    $value = $_.Value -as [int]
    # increment the value
    $value++
    # return the new value
    return $value
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is that since the "release01" is also changing, I cannot include it in the regex, so running this doesn't increment the final value.

Comment: @peepeepoopoo Who said anything about "release01"? :) The regex pattern describes 2 digits preceded by `#define KEYWORD <someCharacters>-` <- doesn't matter if it says `release01` or `peepeepoopoo` or `allyourbasearebelongtous`

Comment: Yep, with just a bit of a change to the regex to match my exact pattern (since I for some reason changed it for this question) I got it to work. This works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen As a follow up question, in your regex is the positive lookbehind an exact match? Meaning if I have both `KEYWORD` and `KEYWORD_2` will this regex recognize both, or only the first.

Comment: @peepeepoopoo Right now it expects a space after `KEYWORD`, but you could remove that space (between `KEYWORD` and `.+`)

Comment: Could you please explain what the '$' in the end of your regex does? I can not for the life of me find a source explaining what it does. Moreso, removing it actually gives me better behavior, in some cases. For example `\d{2}\s*$` does not isolate the number in 'release01-11EXTRATEXT', but `\d{2}\s*` does.