# How to replace value of variable in Javascript (js) file using powershell

Tags: powershell

i've a js file called "env.js"

Content of "env.js":
[image: window.enableReports = true; window.env = window.config.CLIENT_NAME; window.app_version = "Beta-20210907.1"; window.combineDashboard = true;]

How can i replace value of variable "window.app_version" using powershell

P.S i can't use a token as that version is being used by application. i want to update the variable value after every deployment so the only way out is the replace value of variable corresponding to "window.app_version"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I replace every occurrence of a String in a file with PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17144355/how-can-i-replace-every-occurrence-of-a-string-in-a-file-with-powershell)

Comment: @msanford i don't so as i want to set value of variable "window.app_version" to whatever i pass to the function/code.

Comment: Yes, it does: put a token in its place and replace the token. Like `window.app_version = "WINDOW_APP_VERSION";` and then replace the token `WINDOW_APP_VERSION` with PowerShell. This is a very common pattern.

Comment: @msanford i can't use a token as that version is being used by application. i want to update the variable value after every deployment so the only way out is the replace value of variable corresponding to "window.app_version"

Comment: `(Get-Content .\env.js) -Replace '(?<=window\.app_version\s=\s).*', 'OtherVersion' |Set-Content .\env.js`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference to iRon comment:
This Helped me:

Answere:
(Get-Content .\env.js) -Replace '(?<=window.app_version\s=\s).*', 'OtherVersion' |Set-Content .\env.js