# How can I replace strings in multiple files and keep the original file?

Tags: .net, powershell

Many answers show how to replace the text, but I want to keep the original file, I want the replaced file to be in another path and with the new name, such as, rename `test.txt` to `test_replace.txt`.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30893960/19418817)This is the answer I'm reading, I don't know how to improve it to suit my needs

Comment: `[System.IO.File]::WriteAllText("YourNewPath", $content)` maybe?

Answer (score 0):

```
$original_file = "C:\Users\boxman\Documents\test.txt"
$path_copy = "C:\Users\boxman\Documents\test1.txt"

$content = Get-Content -Path $original_file

$content = $content.Replace("1","_9_")

$content | Out-File -FilePath $path_copy
```

This reads file content, replaces what needs to be replaced then creates another item in another path...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).